# Spring boot 2.0.0 multiple databases (data sources)

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, datasource

I want to connect two databases with Spring Boot project. Everything was fine until I migrated to 2.0.0 version. I found some configuration settings but it doesn't work for me.

I am using Oracle database as remote DB and H2 database as file-based local database.

CODE:

REMOTE DATABASE - ORACLE

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "remotedbEntityManagerFactory", basePackages = {"com.stravovani.DB.RemoteDB.Repository"})
public class RemoteDBConfig {

    @Value("${datasource.stravovani.maxPoolSize:10}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "remotedbDataSource")    
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "remotedb.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties();
        HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource)
                DataSourceBuilder
                        .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                        .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                        .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                        .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                        .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                        .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                        .build();
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "remotedbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
            throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.stravovani.DB.RemoteDB.Model");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new
                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager
    transactionManager(@Qualifier("remotedbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

LOCAL DATABASE - H2

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "localdbEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "localdbTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.stravovani.DB.LocalDB.Repository"})
public class LocalDBConfig {

    @Value("${datasource.stravovani.maxPoolSize:10}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    @Bean(name = "localdbDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "localdb.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties();
        HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource)
                DataSourceBuilder
                        .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                        .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                        .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                        .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                        .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                        .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                        .build();
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "localdbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
            throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.stravovani.DB.LocalDB.Model");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new
                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager
    transactionManager(@Qualifier("localdbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

APPLICATION PROPERTIES

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
spring.cache.type=NONE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/localDB

# Oracle - CIT DB
remotedb.datasource.url= ************************
remotedb.datasource.username=*********
remotedb.datasource.password=****************
remotedb.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# H2 - Local DB
localdb.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./localDB
localdb.datasource.username=************
localdb.datasource.password=*********************
localdb.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

ERROR:

```
2018-03-09 21:57:16.707 ERROR 10812 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.stravovani.MVC.Controller.CardController.test(CardController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

**UPDATE**

CARD CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
public class CardController
{
    @Autowired
    public I_CardService i_CardService;
    public CardRepositoryRemote cardRepositoryRemote;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return cardRepositoryRemote.findCardByKartaId("0261549783").toString();
    }

    @PostMapping("/checkcard")
    public @ResponseBody String checkCard(@RequestBody CardRemote cardRemote)
    {
        return i_CardService.checkCard(cardRemote.getKartaId());
    }

    @PostMapping("/savecardtolocaldb")
    public @ResponseBody String saveCardToLocalDB(@RequestBody CardLocal cardLocal){
        return i_CardService.saveCardToLocalDB(cardLocal);
    }

    @GetMapping("/movedata")
    public String moveData(){
        i_CardService.moveData();
        return "Moved";
    }
}
```

REPOSITORY:

```
    @Repository
public interface CardRepositoryRemote extends JpaRepository<CardRemote, String>
{
    CardRemote findCardByKartaId(@Param("kartaId") String kartaId);
}
```

MODEL WITH LOMBOK:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Record")
public class CardLocal
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="LOCAL_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="LOCAL_SEQ", sequenceName="LOCAL_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name = "CARDID")
    private String kartaID;

    @Column(name = "DATE", insertable = false)
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "FOODTYPE")
    private String typJidla;

    @Column(name = "MOVED", insertable = false)
    private boolean moved;

    public CardLocal() {    }

    public CardLocal(String kartaID, String typJidla) {
        this.kartaID = kartaID;
        this.typJidla = typJidla;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your `CardController` auto-wiring the `DataSource`? Which `DataSource` are you injecting? Are there any exceptions occurring when you start your application?

Comment: Yes, can you please show us the actual code where the exception is being thrown. namely: `CardController.java:19`

Comment: I added code for CardController yet

Comment: OK, so cardRepositoryRemote is null. Why do you think it shouldn't be? Hint: this has nothing to do with datasources or the Spring Boot version. And all you need to know about to find out is the code of the controller.

Comment: Well, if I understand, I need to fix the code of CardController, right?

Comment: I removed annotation @Autowired and created basic constructor and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

With spring boot 2.0 there was a shift to Hikari for database transaction management.  Hikari requires the datasource url to be defined as **spring.datasource.jdbcUrl** where it used to be **spring.datasource.url**.

If you are using a custom 2nd datasource it will also need to use the jdbcUrl syntax, for example: **oracle.datasource.jdbcUrl**. The spring documentation messes this up in [their example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource) where they define the jdbc URL as jdbc-url.

The rest of the spring documentation on how to configure multiple data sources is very useful.